# Android Async http requests, should I make three different classes?

Tags: java, android, http, android-asynctask

I'm a beginner in Java and coding for Android. When I was coding an app which makes some network requests, I got NetworkOnMainThreadException exception. I googled and found out the reason and solution. But I still have a question. My app makes requests on different sites and will does different actions with responses (first response on login action, it will be checked, second action is some api calls, third action is requesting images), I think I should not make three different classes for each case (doInBackground is the same, but different onPostExecute methods will be here). How can I fix this problem? Thanks

Comment: I think the easiest way is just getting response as a returned value. But the ideas with callbacks and interfaces are good too. I want to clarify: this is a part of test task for getting to an internship and I have to reduce monkey code as much as I can. But all these (and mine too) are looking for me not the best solutions ;(

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an aditional variable as doInBackground Params, save it as "global" class variable and switch in onPostExecute so u dont have to make 3 different classes

Like this

```
public class Async_DL extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
    String type_of_request;
    String url;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

        this.url = params[0];
        this.type_of_request = params[1];

        doinBackground stuff....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        switch(this.type_of_request){
            case a:
                do some stuff
            break;
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to create an interface callback like this

```
interface Callback { 
     public void call (String response); //or whatever return type you want
}
```

Then you might extends your AsyncTask class like this

```
private class HttpTask extends AsyncTask <Void,Void,String> {
     Callback callback;
     HttpTask (Callback callback) {
          this.callback = callback;
     }
     // your doInBackground method
     @Override
     protected void onPostExecute (String response) {
          callback.call(response);
     }
 }
```

Then you might call your `AsyncTask` like this

```
new HttpTask (new Callback () {
     @Override
     public void call (String response) { /* Here goes implementation */ }
}).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to make three separate classes for each action. You can extend only once the AsyncTask and i would suggest to add an interface call which can be implemented by your activity:

```
public interface RequestListener {

    public void onLoginCall();

    public void onApiCall();

    public void onImageCall();
}
```

At the same time create an enumeration to hold the requests' types:

```
public enum RequestType{

    LOGIN,
    API,
    IMAGE;
}
```

Meanwhile you can extend the AsyncTask and call the necessary listener's methods per each case. You can use the second attribute to hold the type of the request:

```
public class RequestTask extends AsyncTask<Object, RequestType, Object> {
    private RequestListener listener;


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Object... params) {

        this.url = params[0];
        this.type_of_request = params[1];

        doinBackground stuff....
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Object result) {
       if(result is from login)
         listener.onLoginCall();
         ... and so on
    }

}
```

Comment: if(result is from login). How can I find out this? This is just a json text. How can I point this when calling to execute() ?

Comment: you can set a parameter in the AsyncTask before calling execute

Comment: or you can use the second parameter of the AsyncTask to set the request type.